# How to call index of vector in matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have:  n-by-3 matrix A, and n-by-1 matrix B:

```
  A=[ x1 y1 z1           
      x2 y2 z2
      x3 y3 z3
      x4 y4 z4
      .......
      xn yn zn ]

B=[ 3           
    2
    7
    1
    ...
    n ]
```

`B` is index (labelling) matrix of `A`.

I wanna assign the vector `A` to vector `B`.

Ex:

```
(x1 y1 z1) assign to 1
(x3 y3 z3) assign to 3
......................
```

`(xn yn zn)` assign to `n`

Instead of working with matrix `A`, I can work with "labelling" matrix `B`.
and then

- when I call `3` in matrix `B`, it will show the value (x3 y3 z3) from matrix `A`.
- when I call `7` in matrix `B`, it will show the value (x7 y7 z7) from matrix `A`.
- when I call `[3,7]` in matrix `B`, it will show the value matrix

  ```
    `C=[ x3 y3 z3
         x7 y7 z7 ]`
  ```

from matrix `A`.

- when I call `n` in matrix `B`, it will show the value (xn yn zn) from matrix `A`.
- and vice versa (I call `(x3 y3 z3)` from `A`, it will show `3` in `B`.....)

How to write a code to call matrix `A` from matrix `B` , and vice versa?
(the numbers `3,2,7,1,....n`: in matrix `B` are arbitrary numbers)

Detailed Example:
I have:  6-by-3 matrix A

```
  A=[ 15 2 -1        ---> labelling "1"   
      51 6 -3        ---> labelling "2"
      89 9  1        ---> labelling "3"
      0  4  5        ---> labelling "4"
      0  0  9        ---> labelling "5"
      10 4 -5 ]      ---> labelling "6"
```

.................................
...I will do some algorithm.......
..................................

..................................
And, I get the "labelling matrix B" output result........

```
  B=[ 6           
      1 
      5 ]
```

I wanna to get back the value in matrix A from B-->

```
  C=[ 10 4 -5           
      15 2 -1
      0  0 9 ]
```

How to write a code to show the relationship between A, B,C ? (or how to call matrix C from A &B )

Comment: x1,x2,x3...xn : are the number.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do. Can you give us an example of what you mean by calling these matrices (even if it doesn't work correctly)? Are you trying to get something like `A(B(k),:)`?

Comment: please see "detailed example" in question. Hope my detailed example is clear to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) can be done simply with:

```
C = A(B, :);
```

In other words, `B` is just used as the row index into `A` to select the rows, and all the columns for those rows are selected with [`:`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3;
    4,5,6;
    7,8,9]
a(1,:)
a(2,:)
a(3,:)
```

> a =
>
> ```
>  1     2     3
>  4     5     6
>  7     8     9
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>  1     2     3
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>  4     5     6
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>  7     8     9
> ```

Comment: i think you don't understand my question. anyway,thanks